# SSRS Count Fields in DataSet for Map Report

Tags: reporting-services, dataset

So I have these 2 lists in SharePoint i.e. Producer & Movies.

Now I need to create a single dataset with information about a producer (Name & Nationality) and a count of his/her movies. So an example record from the dataset should look like this for example: Steven Spielberg | USA | 20

I have been looking for way to do this but I couldn't find anything. Everything I tried resulted in an error on the report at runtime. Like when I tried to use a LookUpSet-function that should have worked if it were allowed to use a LookUpSet-function in a DataSet.

Does anyone know how I would be able to achieve something like this?

Sorry if I'm not clear with the title but I didn't know how else to describe it, so any suggestions are appreciated as well. :)

Kind regards
Gravinco

Answer (score 1):

By default, we can only get values from one list in one query, which means we can only have one list in one dataset. Even you can create a calculated fields to return the related movies of the producer, it's still not supported to use aggregation function in it to get the count value. So for your requirement, You have to create two datasets and do the aggregation on producer group level in table.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, could you maybe elaborate a bit more on that last sentence?